# Hibernate MassIndexer using chained invocation for building a batch job

Tags: java, hibernate, fluent-interface

I've a class called `MassIndexer.java` [(on GitHub)](https://github.com/mincong-h/gsoc-hsearch/blob/4b8f5525a9ab716618bb42f0b90de0e5d77f5ec9/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/jsr352/MassIndexer.java) and it uses chained invocation for building a batch job. Each method assigns a property of this job and finally the job will be started using method `MassIndexer#start()`. Here's an example for Java EE:

```
long executionId = new MassIndexer()
        .addRootEntities(Company.class, Employee.class)
        .start();
```

According to different environments, the requirement is different. Some methods are required in Java SE while all of them are optional in Java EE. If users use `MassIndexer` under Java SE and they forget to set the properties through those required methods, the job will fail. These required methods on Java SE are:

- `isJavaSE(boolean)`
- `entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory)`
- `jobOperator(JobOperator)`

Here's another example for Java SE:

```
long executionId = new MassIndexer()
        .addRootEntities(Company.class, Employee.class)
        .isJavaSE(true)
        .entityManagerFactory(emf)
        .jobOperator(jobOperator)
        .start();
```

However, the design of this class in not clear: **people don't know which method is required and which isn't.** The only way to know it is to read the documentation. And I'm wondering how can I improve the design of this class, so that people can easily understand what to do and how to do. For example, should this class be split into `MassIndexerEE` and `MassIndexerSE`? Should it be refactored into a builder class, e.g. `BatchIndexingJobBuilder`?

**And there's no order or logic among these methods.** You can call `foo()` then `bar()`, but `bar()` then `foo()` works too. Properties are used for configurations based on

- selection of class types (about persistence)
- database interaction (about persistence)
- parallel processing (about job)
- checkpoing algorithm (about job)

Someone must be confused when using this class, so I'm seeking advice.  Every review is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a second level Builder class

```
long executionId = new MassIndexer()
        .addRootEntities(Company.class, Employee.class)
        .javaSE()
        .entityManagerFactory(emf)
        .jobOperator(jobOperator)
        .start();

long executionId = new MassIndexer()
        .addRootEntities(Company.class, Employee.class)
        .javaEE()
        .start();

class MassIndexer
    MassIndexer addRootEntities(Class<?>...)
    SEBuilder javaSE()
    EEBuilder javaEE()

class MassIndexer.SEBuilder
    long start()
    SEBuilder entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory)
...
```

- I am not that happy with the name and using a constructor for MassIndexer
- addRootEntities might go in the "constructor"
- javaSE/EE maybe standalone/server or container?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid allowing the invocation chain to go from a valid object to an invalid object. Your `setJavaSE` allows that.

Instead you can make a method `configureJavaSE(EntityManagerFactory, JobOperator)` which takes all the required configuration items for setting javaSE to true.